# python dict.update() equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I want to update the dictionary in javascript- modify the existing values or add new values- same as python dictionary update.

dict+ or dict.update() seem not be working. Is it possible to do so in javascript?

Thanks in advance!

```
data={"abc":{1:2,3:4}}

if (key in d) {
            d[key].update(data[key]);
        }
        else {
            d[key]={};
            d[key]=data[key];
        }
```

EDIT: The updating dictionary is working fine as follow-

```
dg={"abc":{1:2,3:4},"sdc":{1:2,4:5}}
function upd(data) {
    for (key in data) {
        if (key in dg) {
            for (key2 in data[key]) {
                dg[key][key2]=data[key][key2];
            }
        }
        else {
            dg[key]={};
            for (key2 in data[key]) {
                dg[key][key2]=data[key][key2];
            }
        }
```

but if i try separating the function as-

```
var old={};
var new={};
function update_dict(old,new) {
console.log(new,old);
    for (key2 in new) {
                old[key2]=new[key2];
            }
    return old;
}
function upd(data) {
for (key in data) {
    if (key in dg) {
        dg[key]=update_dict(dg[key],data[key]);
    }
    else {
        dg[key]={};
        dg[key]=update_dict(dg[key],data[key]);
    }
```

It is throwing an error saying **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token new**. I have really tried a lot of permutations, please suggest. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you creating your dictionary, can you upload some of your code?

Comment: `new` is a reserved keyword. Try using some other word, like `new_dict`.

Comment: Would you reconsider your accepted answer? ;-)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
const first_dict = { 'key_one': 'value_one', 'key_two': 'value_two' } 
const second_dict = { 'key_one': 'value_from_second_dict', 'key_three': 'value_three' }

const accumulative = {
  ...first_dict,
  ...second_dict
}

console.log(accumulative)

/* 
[object Object] {
  key_one: "value_from_second_dict",
  key_three: "value_three",
  key_two: "value_two"
}
*/
```

Comment: It works for objects, too!? Awesome. This is the correct answer!

Comment: This is ECMA6, but has widespread support: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-spread_(...)_operator

Comment: In Chrome 70, `Object.assign` is more than an order of magnitude faster than destructuring assignment. And in Firefox 62, it is nearly four times faster. See @CasualCoder3's answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Python equivalent is `d1 = {**d2, **d3)`

Answer (score 16):

You can use `Object.assign()` to get the job done. It will create a new object with all the keys updated as well as add any new key value pairs to the newly created object.

```js
const target = {c: 4, d: 5}
const source = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

const newObj = Object.assign({}, target, source);

console.log(newObj); //=> {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 5}
```

Note that `Object.assign()` modifies the first argument which is why we're passing an empty object above.

You can even pass in a sequence of objects to update the `target` object, check out the [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for more info

Comment: In Chrome 70 and Firefox 62, `Object.assign` is fastest by a wide margin. Using for-in is second fastest. Slowest by a wide margin is the spread operator (...) with destructuring assignment.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `target` gets both modified and returned, so no need for `newObj` as in this example (that variable name is misleading since its not a new object but just `target` modified).

Answer (score 5):

- If you are using a `Map` instance, just call `yourMap.set(key, newValue)`.
- If you are using a basic JavaScript object, just use either:

  - Dot-notation `yourObject.yourProperty = newValue`
  - Square brackets `yourObject['your-property'] = newValue`

There's no "bulk" update like Python. That will depend on how you structure your data and how deep down you need to go.

Comment: @user2715898 you should be asking another question

Answer (score 4):

```js
function update_dic(a,b){
 for(key in b){
  a[key]     = b[key]
    }
 return a;
}
var  a = {1:45,4:56}
var b  = {1:56,6:67,67:67}
a = update_dic(a,b)
console.log(a)
```

Comment: var obj1 = {'a':1,'b':6};
var obj2 = {'b':2,'c':3};
Object.assign(obj1,obj2) ;
console.log(obj1)

Comment: This would be more correct without the return (and removing `a =` in the second last line. Python's dict.update does in-place updating, and doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash `assign` function should do the trick. See https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#assign